# is it possible to appeal against a sentance of life imprisonment without possibility of reduction passed by the supreme court in India?

Tags: india

https://indiankanoon.org/doc/50602236/

It has been held that the supreme court can pass a sentance that would bar someone from seeking sentance reduction/remmission under crpc 432 and 433

can such a decision be appealed against the supreme court itself ?